# Use data from a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've written a function which outputs data to a paragraph with the syntax

```
<p id="csvData"></p>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use the data from this paragraph. For example

```
var add= csvData + 2
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: How did you put the data into that paragraph in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the data is numeric you need to

1. Get the text of the element: `document.querySelector('#csvData').innerHTML;`
2. Convert it to a number: use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`
3. Use it as you see fit

so

```
var csvData = parseInt( document.querySelector('#csvData').innerHTML, 10 ),
    add = csvData + 2;
```

or

```
var csvData = parseFloat( document.querySelector('#csvData').innerHTML ),
    add = csvData + 2;
```

---

Demo

```js
var csvData = parseInt( document.querySelector('#csvData').innerHTML, 10 ),
    add = csvData + 2

console.log( 'result of addition:', add );
```

```html
<p id="csvData">150</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the element first so in your js tag or in your js file use the `getElementById` method

```
var paragraph = document.getElementById('csvData')
```

if you want to get the text from paragraph you need to use the `paragraph.innerHTML` property

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM you can get the textContent data of your paragraph, convert it to int with parseInt then do your math.

```
<p id="csvData">1</p>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var s = document.getElementById('csvData').textContent;
    var i = parseInt(s);
    alert(i+1);
</script>
```